# How to activate another tab after reloading the same php file clicking on a button

Tags: php, javascript, button, tabs

My users.php file is:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['attrname'])){ 
//insert some stuff to the sql base

} ?> 

    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#usertablediv" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="#attrdiv" data-toggle="tab">Attributes</a></li>
            </ul>

    <div id="users_attributes" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="usertablediv">
        <table>some stuff about users</table></div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="attrdiv">
         <table>some stuff about attributes of users </table>
        </div>
        </div>

      <form method='post' action='users.php'>
     <input type="text" name="attrname" id='attrname'>
     <button class='btn btn-primary'type='submit'>Save</button>
    </form>
```

When I click on the button 'Save', I would like users.php to be reloaded with the Attributes tab activated this time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply want to change your PHP codes so that it updates the class attribute:

```
// First list item:
<li class="<?php echo isset($_POST['attrname']) ? '' : 'active'; ?>">
// Second list item:
<li class="<?php echo isset($_POST['attrname']) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: <div class="tab-pane <?php echo isset($_POST['attrname']) ? '' : 'active'; ?>" id="usertablediv">

Answer (score 1):

No need to specify `users.php` as this is the same file, so you may change the form to

```
<form method='post'>
```

You can check with PHP if the users clicked the "Save" button with `isset($_POST["attrname"])` so that

```
<? if (isset($_POST["attrname"])){ ?>
// html if user pressed the button
<? } else { ?>
// html if user didn't pressed the button
} ?>
```